# Is it true that $\mathbb{R}^m \cap \mathbb{R}^n = \emptyset$ where $m \neq n$

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

Is it true that $\mathbb{R}^m \cap \mathbb{R}^n = \emptyset$ where $m \neq n$ ?

I would say that it is true because the elements in each set are different entities. This means that one set cannot be a subset of the other. An example would be $\mathbb{R} \cap \mathbb{R}^2$. You cannot say that $1 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ for example.

Comment: That is correct, but what has this to do with [tag:probability-theory]?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos
Doesn't probability theory work with sets and their intersections as well?

Comment: Sure, as most branches of Mathematics do. If that's all that you are interested in, then I suggest that you tag your question as [tag:elementary-set-theory].

Comment: I added the tag. I understand my question is general, but this is the area I came across the question thus I added it as the tag.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Isnt $\mathbb{R}^0 \cap \mathbb{R}^1 \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: @Eminem What *is* $\Bbb R^0$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos a singleton, the zero vector space.

Comment: @Eminem I would agree if you had stated $\{0 \} \cap \mathbb{R} \neq \varnothing$ but the use of the notation $\mathbb{R}^0$ is misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, these sets are disjoint.

To see this, define the ordered pair
$$(x,y) = \{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$$
and extend this definition to $n$-tuples
$$(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = ((x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}),x_n).$$
So $n$-tuples are sets and we have clear notion of equality of two sets:
$$A= B :\Longleftrightarrow \forall x[x\in A\Leftrightarrow x\in B].$$
Equality of two $n$-tuples is then given by
$$(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)\Leftrightarrow \forall i[x_i=y_i].$$
Taking this into accout you see that the above sets are disjoint if $m\ne n$.

Answer (score 1):

From rigorous point of set theory, the answer is yes. However, taking your example, let's assume the mapping $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$ such that $x\mapsto (x,0)$ for example. Clearly, $f$ is bijective. Hence, it's safe to say that the image of $f$, namely $\mathbb R\times\{0\}$, represents the domain of $f$ i.e. $\mathbb R\sim\mathbb R\times\{0\}\subset\mathbb R^2$.

Therefore, $\mathbb R$ can be seen, in this way, as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ and the intersection $\mathbb R\cap\mathbb R^2$ is not empty (disregarding difference in structures of elements in both sets).

I hope that example answers your question since generalizing that is relatively easy. Also, may I recommend reading about disjoint unions as a way to view unions of sets that do intersect. A lot of similar logic is used.